# How to put SVG with clipping path and mask inside image src?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have been trying for quite a while now to put dynamically generated SVG in an image "src" attribute and have been successful with the simple shapes but this one with clipping path and mask just doesn't work.

Did I do something wrong. (Tried with "use" and "defs" but no luck)

Any help is appreciated. Example:

```js
 function createSVG(){

      const ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
      const shapeSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
      shapeSvg.setAttribute('width', '50px');
      shapeSvg.setAttribute('height', '50px');

      shapeSvg.setAttribute("width", "50px");
      shapeSvg.setAttribute("height", "50px");

      // Make clipping path
      const clipPath = document.createElementNS(ns, "clipPath");
      clipPath.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "clipPath");

      const cPath = document.createElementNS(ns, "path");
      cPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M 25 0 A 25 25, 0, 1, 1, 0 25 L 0 0 Z");
      clipPath.appendChild(cPath);

      shapeSvg.appendChild(clipPath);

      // Make mask path
      const mask = document.createElementNS(ns, "mask");
      mask.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "circleMask");

      const mRect = document.createElementNS(ns, "rect");
      mRect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 0);
      mRect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 0);
      mRect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "50px");
      mRect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "50px");
      mRect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "white");
      mask.appendChild(mRect);

      const mCircle = document.createElementNS(ns, "circle");
      mCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 25);
      mCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 25);
      mCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 25);
      mCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "black");
      mask.appendChild(mCircle);

      shapeSvg.appendChild(mask);

      const tailPath = document.createElementNS(ns, "path");
      tailPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M 0 0 L 0 25 L 25 0 Z");
      tailPath.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "black");
      tailPath.setAttributeNS(null, "mask", "url(#circleMask)");
      shapeSvg.appendChild(tailPath);

      const tearPath = document.createElementNS(ns, "path");
      tearPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M 25 0 A 25 25, 0, 1, 1, 0 25 L 0 0 Z");
      tearPath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
      tearPath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "3");
      tearPath.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
      tearPath.setAttributeNS(null, "clip-path", "url(#clipPath)");

      shapeSvg.appendChild(tearPath);
      return shapeSvg;
    }

    (function createShape(){
      const container = document.body;
      
      
      const svg = createSVG();
      document.body.prepend(svg);
      var xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);

      var image = document.createElement('img');
      image.src = `data:image/svg+xml,${xml}`;
      image.style.cssText = `
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
      `;
      
      container.appendChild(image);
      return container;
    })();
```

If you remove the part for setting the attributes for clipping-path and mask it works but the result is as you can guess. What part is generated or serialized wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The value for the src won't do. Please take a look at this pen https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs?editors=0010 to see how to encode the value fort the src. You need something like this:

Comment: `<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50px' height='50px'%3E%3CclipPath id='clipPath'%3E%3Cpath d='M 25 0 A 25 25, 0, 1, 1, 0 25 L 0 0 Z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3Cmask id='circleMask'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='50px' height='50px' fill='white'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3Ccircle cx='25' cy='25' r='25' %3E%3C/circle%3E%3C/mask%3E%3Cpath d='M 0 0 L 0 25 L 25 0 Z' mask='url(%23circleMask)'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 25 0 A 25 25, 0, 1, 1, 0 25 L 0 0 Z' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' fill='none' clip-path='url(%23clipPath)'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E">`

Comment: Data URLS are URLs. You must URLencode all the reserved URL characters, such as `#`, `=` etc.  Or Base64 encode it.

Comment: Thanks guys, as soon as I saw a duplicate sign and the original post I was aware of the problem. Fixed it. Thanks.